# Open a a Linux-Binary in a Shell-File (*.sh)

Tags: linux, shell

so, I'm trying to execute a Program with sudo-permissions.

i programmed this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
    echo "Bestätigen sie ihr Passwort, damit der Compiler mit erhöhten Rechten gestartet werden kann" 
    [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ] && exec sudo -- "$0" "$@"
    sudo ~./Compiler/Compiler_Project
```

the problem is: i get asked my password; until then everything is fine. But then, i't cant open my file. The case-Sensitivity is not the problem: it's properly cased

```
I hope, you can help me; I am a linux-Newb.
```

Comment: `~./...` is not a valid path (on the vast majority of systems). `~/` indicates the current user's home directory (and will not be what you expect a new inside a sudo'd script. `./` indicates the current working directory. `~./` would be the home directory of the user `.`, of there were such a user (which is unlikely).

Comment: I'll try it  EDIT: IT WORKED!!!

Comment: Use `$HOME` rather than `~` in scripts. Both works, but `$HOME` is more descriptive.

Comment: Why would you want/need to start a compiler as root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to expand your "~" inside your script.

```
!/bin/sh

eval var=~/Compiler/Compiler_Project
sudo $var
```

Comment: EDIT: i tried to do ./... in the variable. THANK YOU!

Comment: i did. I am new here, so i haven't seen it.

Comment: That is why I ask for :-)